# curl 403 forbidden

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

I am getting a 'You don't have permission to access /rest/02/put.php on this server.' message while using following.

This is put-service-consumer.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1/rest/02/put.php';
$fh = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
$data = file_get_contents('data.txt');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This is put-service.php

```
<?php
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
echo $putdata."here";
$fp = fopen("put_data_file.txt", "a");
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

This is an example from restful php webservice book. While examples for get and post works, examples for delete and put isn't working.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Is your webserver configured to accept PUT ?

Comment: I am using wamp locally. How can I check/enable that?

Comment: Hi thanks. I configured it now.

Comment: Do you still get the error after configuring `PUT` ?

Comment: Yes, still getting the error. I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying a tutorial from [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/). While example for post and get is working. PUT and Delete is giving 403 error. Folders permission are for full access.

Answer (score 1):

This may aid in debugging: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/faceofpmfclkengnkgkgjkcibdbhemoc

That's a great tool I use to work with REST APIs.